# The name of the Site Collection does not appear in the service query

Tags: javascript, spfx, pnp, react

Could you help me please, I try to understand, why the site collection doesn't appear in my service query?
This way, I get an error:[image: query to get list data]

This is my service to get data from list:

```
export class PersonService implements IPersonService {
  public get(): Promise<Array<Person>> {
    let users = new Array<Person>();
    const processResultUsers = (items: Array<Person>):void => { users = users.concat(items); };
    const birthdays = this.getBirthdays();
    birthdays
      .then(processResultUsers)
      .catch(error => { console.error(error); });
    return Promise.all([birthdays]).then(() => {
      return users.sort((a, b) => a.eventDate.valueOf() - b.eventDate.valueOf());
    });
  }

private getBirthdays(): Promise<Array<Person>> {
    return sp.web.lists.getById(Settings.listPersonal).items
      .select('*',
        `${Fields.Employee}/EMail`,
        `${Fields.Employee}/Id`,
        `${Fields.Employee}/FirstName`,
        `${Fields.Employee}/LastName`)
      .expand(Fields.Employee)
      .get().then((usersList) => {
        return usersList
          .filter(item => item[Fields.BDDate] !== null)
          .map(item => {
        return {
          id: personType.Birthdays + item.Id,
          firstName: item[Fields.Employee].FirstName,
          lastName: item[Fields.Employee].LastName,
          email: item[Fields.Employee].EMail,
          userId: item[Fields.Employee].Id,
          eventDate: moment(item[Fields.BDDate]),
          eventType: item[Fields.BDDate] !== null ? moment(item[Fields.BDDate]).format('MMM DD') : '',
          type: personType.Birthdays
        };
      });
    });
  }
```

And I get this data from service in my web-part component to render.

```
private loadData():Promise<Array<Person>>{
    return this.props.service.get().then((result: Array<Person>) => {
      return result;
    });
  }
```

My .ts file with onInit method:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/pnpjs";

export default class EmployeesEventsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IEmployeesEventsWebPartProps> {
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return super.onInit().then(_ => {
      sp.setup({
        spfxContext: this.context as any
      });
    });
  }

  public render(): void {
    let service = new PersonService();
    }

    const element: React.ReactElement<IEmployeesEventsProps > = React.createElement(
      EmployeesEvents,
      {
        title: this.properties.title,
        seeAllLink: this.properties.showAllLink,
        showAll: this.properties.showAll,
        isOpenInNewTab: this.properties.shouldOpenNewTab,
        service: service,
        profilePageUrl: this.properties.profilePageUrl,
        displayNumber: this.properties.numberOfItemsToDisplay
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }
```

My package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.16.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.16.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.16.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.16.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.16.1",
    "@pnp/pnpjs": "^2.0.13",
    "@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "3.12.0",
    "@pnp/spfx-property-controls": "3.11.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.199.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-facebook": "9.0.12",
    "react-instagram-carousel": "^2.0.1",
    "react-social-media-embed": "2.3.3",
    "react-twitter-widgets": "1.11.0",
    "tslib": "2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.5": "0.2.2",
    "@rushstack/eslint-config": "2.5.1",
    "@microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx": "1.16.1",
    "@microsoft/eslint-config-spfx": "1.16.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.16.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "~1.15.2",
    "ajv": "^6.12.5",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.5.5",
    "@types/react": "17.0.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.17",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.49.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.16.1"
  }
```

Comment: Have you initialized PnPjs in your webpart's init method?

Comment: @theChrisKent, yes, I added additional code with onInit method above

Comment: which version of PnPjs are you using?

Comment: @Propool, try using latest version of PnP JS library and follow this documentation for proper setup: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela, "@pnp/pnpjs": "^2.0.13".
I've just added my package.json file above.

Comment: I noticed that if there is a "/" at the end of the URL, then everything works fine, if there is no "/", then it doesn't work.
`https://srelnz.sharepoint.com/sites/SrelIntra` - doesn't work.
`https://srelnz.sharepoint.com/sites/SrelIntra/` - works fine.